# How to Navigate to the different screens after clicking on List Item?

Tags: flutter, listview

I am getting my data through Hive to ListView, here is my code where I am showing ListView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/Database/Hive/PasswordModel.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/screens/home_screen/passwords/ShowData.dart';

class PasswordsNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PasswordsNavigationState createState() => _PasswordsNavigationState();
}

class _PasswordsNavigationState extends State<PasswordsNavigation> {

  var passwordBox = Hive.box<PasswordModel>('passwordBox');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: _buildListView(),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return WatchBoxBuilder(
      box: passwordBox,
      builder: (context, box) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> raw = box.toMap();
        List list = raw.values.toList();

        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            PasswordModel passwordModel = list[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(passwordModel.websiteName),
              subtitle: Text(passwordModel.websiteAddress),
              trailing: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: (){
                      passwordBox.deleteAt(index);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have created a new .dart file named ShowData.dart When I click on any item then how to open this activity? I don't know how to navigate to new screen when i click on list item also i want data like list index n all with navigator.

Comment: The `ListTile()` has an onTap method. For navigation check out the https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably create a new widget for the page, like this:

```dart
class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  DetailsPage({Key key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  final int id;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show details for the item with the given id.
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that it also takes an `id` parameter in the constructor.

Then, in the `ListTile`'s `onTap` method, you can navigate to the new page, passing along the `id`:

```dart
ListTile(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => DetailsPage(id: /* id of the item at the current index */),
    ));
  },
  ...
),
```